# EP1429795A1 Is there an English version available? Why is no downloadable PDF version available?

Tags: google-patents, bulk-download

In reference to the patent: [WO2003028746A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2003028746A1)

Comment: As far as I can tell it hasn't been filed in any English language countries. You can get a pdf at The Lens, but it is in German. https://www.lens.org/images/patent/WO/2003028746/A1/WO_2003_028746_A1.pdf